# How to get htaccess to load page without file extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I have searched around and tried a few different things, with no luck.

I am trying to load this page http://SERVERNAME.com/get.php when I use the url http://SERVERNAME.com/get

Here is what I have in my htaccess now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

I have tested to make sure my htaccess file is being read by intentionally breaking it and getting a 500 error.

Comment: Do the actual files on the server have a .php extention or not?

Comment: yes they do. I can load http://SERVERNAME.com/get.php like normal. I just want to be able to remove the .php from the URL and have the page load also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(?:GET|POST)\ /.*\.php\ HTTP.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
```